# MySQL Databases Online

Tags: mysql, database

I recently downloaded the community version of MySQL. I'm relatively new to databases and all so I may have some misconceptions about databases. However, based on my understanding, the database downloaded is local to my computer, so if my computer ever gets destroyed or wiped then the databases is not accessible anymore and cannot be referenced by programs.

If this is the case, is there a way to make the database not local to my computer, but based online so that it will always be accessible regardless of the condition of my computer?

EDIT: It would be best if the database was free if possible. In addition, I have no host accounts currently.

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/rds/ , online db

Comment: Tell us more about your needs and whether or not you currently have any host accounts. If you do then likely you already have a 24/7 db. Can u afford $100/year

Comment: @noobProgrammer What is the database being used for? A web application? Are multiple users using it? It's very difficult to answer the question without this information.

Comment: Well since aws ec2 etc is free sort of play with it. Keep in mind u are running a dummy downed vps with 600mb ram and 1/200 timeslice on zenserver so dont judge aws capabilities on that lameness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the database on your machine, then true - if the computer gets wiped or destroyed, so does your database and data.

If you want online, then Amazon Web Services (AWS) is probably your best bet. You create an RDS there, and it lives in the cloud. Not for the faint of heart. Not that it is particularly difficult, but probably not for the novice.

Comment: I see. Are there any free ones since AWS is only free for a year.

Comment: I found one online. Do you know what I would but for the host name (for JDBC)?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and the solution came from [here](http://www.vps.me)
All the free hosters i found with mySQL were way too limited and 99% didn't gave you remote connections.
So you set up a free VPS ...a nice linux distro,you install the mySQL and off you go...